# facebook api: do i need to store each user's friends list in order to create a who's online component (between friends)?

Tags: facebook

this is a generic question about a facebook application creation.

I want the user to have a `who's online` component that shows who's among his friends are currently using the application.

does it mean that i actually need to store each user's friends list in my own database and to filter from that the users that are currently using my application ?

that seems like a lot of work.

it even means that each time that the user uses my application i should fetch and store his friends list all over again just to make sure it wasn't changed.

is there any other way?

as you see i didn't explained what programming language i use because i think it's irrelevant to the question.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to store friend ids as you can get this info from Facebook (by running FQL on [`friend`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend) table). Just store user ids who are currently logged in (probably need `last_seen` timestamp on user table, then searching for users who were interacting with the app withing last 15 min).

So, something like this:

- Whenever a user interacts with the app update user's `last_seen` timestamp
- On user login retrieve friend ids through FQL and store them in a session if you don't want to retrieve this list every pageview (friend list most likely won't change during login session)
- Search for friend ids among currently active users when needed